# How to set background image full as per screen size without giving height and make content center into it

Tags: html, css

I have tried with padding but I think it's the wrong way to give 200px padding to HTML content can you please help me what to do?

[how to make this same for all resolution screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwLDd.jpg)

Comment: Not sure how you expect anyone to help you with this when you haven't shown us any of your existing HTML, CSS or JS

Comment: I have put this CSS

#firstBlock{
    background-image: url('../img/bg.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 350px 0px;


}
@jaydeeppatel

Comment: you should add padding-bottom:100% @hina thakkar

Comment: @Ranjithv

it's working but on the small screen, image is not looking good

Comment: pls share some kind of code

Comment: @Ranjithv

can you please check

#firstBlock{ background-image: url('../img/bg.png'); background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-attachment: fixed; text-align: center; padding: 350px 0px; }

Comment: You really should edit your original question to show your code. This link might however put you on the right path: https://codetheweb.blog/2017/12/07/fullscreen-image-hero/

Comment: @hina thakkar you should add padding bottom 100%

Comment: its really helpful thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```css
.hero
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #000 url("https://crowdforangels.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/notebook-1280538_1920.jpg") no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .hero .overlay
    {
        color: #fff;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1>WEB & GRAPHIC DESIGNER</h1>
    <a href="#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>
</section>
```